# How does Linux upgrade packages that are in use?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I am using Arch Linux and I can do a system upgrade while surfing the net for example. How can the browser package be upgraded if the program itself is in use? Or the Kernel for example? Doesn't the executable need to be stopped in order to be replaced with a new one? Or does it happen at the next reboot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The browser files on disc just get replaced. The running program (if not completely in memory) keeps the old executable files open until the program closes (but until then those are no longer the executables files you get via the directory entries). On the next restart of the browser you get the version.

No reboot necessary except for the program that gets loaded at reboot (i.e. the kernel) There are programs that patch the kernel in place, not even requiring a reboot for that, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: I know Debian does something like this. Is this kind of approach standard across distributions? Does it require significant support by the package manager? And if so, what? Just curious.

Comment: Does that mean there's an update process that watches for the old executable files to be closed, then it jumps in & deletes them / replaces them with the new executables?

Comment: @Xen2050 the files only exist because the process that has them open, on closing the kernel releases the file, I don't think there is separate process watching that, AFAIK the kernel keeps count, just like with hardlinks.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'll try to search for references, IIRC this worked on Irix as well when I used that in the mid 90's. It is IMO not Debian specific.

Comment: The old executable file that's running I mean, for example `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` that's open while I'm running firefox, it exists whether or not firefox is running. How is the old executable file replaced by the new one, without crashing/closing firefox? If it's kept open & not deleted so it doesn't crash firefox, then when/how does it get deleted?

Comment: @Xen2050 There is no such thing as the file being "replaced". The directory entry is deleted, without the file data being touched, and a new file is created, with a directory entry that points to a new file. The old file is still there.

Comment: You mean like the inode, so `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` "points to" the new executable file instead of the old one. I think I've got that part, but how does the old file get deleted after it's not needed by the running firefox anymore? Does the kernel delete them somehow? --- Maybe I'm not following, is there a link to another explanation handy? Thanks

Comment: @Xen2050 - try this: `{ rm /tmp/"$$".tmp; echo nope still here >&3; ls -l /tmp/"$$".tmp /dev/fd/3; read var <&3; echo "$var"; } 3<>/tmp/"$$".tmp` - the kernel's file-system, really *the* file-system, tracks open files for every running process and maintains those descriptors in VFS. They may no longer have a claim on disk-space as they are unlinked, but for as long as there is a reader/writer with a claim to them they still exist *somewhere.*

Answer (score 7):

As you suspected, Unix-like systems prevent most files being executed from being overwritten. Here's what the standard says about the [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) system call:

> The open() function may fail if:
>
> [ETXTBSY] The file is a pure procedure (shared text) file that is being executed and oflag is O_WRONLY or O_RDWR.

But a file being executed can still be *unlinked*, and that's how the package managers do their work.

Here's what `dpkg` on Debian and Ubuntu does when installing the new version of `/bin/cpio` that just came out:

```
open("/bin/cpio.dpkg-new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0) = 10
// lots of reads and writes omitted from this listing.
// It's copying the new version into dpkg-new
fchown(10, 0, 0)                  = 0 
fchmod(10, 0755)                  = 0 
close(10)                         = 0 
rename("/bin/cpio.dpkg-new", "/bin/cpio") = 0
```

In detail, this:

- copies the new version to `cpio.dpkg-new` in the same directory as `cpio`.
- sets the owner and file permissions to whatever the package says they should be
- renames `cpio.dpkg-new` to `cpio`

The way to safely install a new version of a file without ever being in the position of the file not existing, even for an instant, is to use the [rename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) system call. This requires both files to be in the same filesystem, and that's why dpkg created the new version of cpio in the same directory as the old version. The standard says:

> int rename(const char *old, const char *new);
>
> The rename() function shall change the name of a file. The old argument points to the pathname of the file to be renamed. The new argument points to the new pathname of the file.
>
> If the link named by the new argument exists, it shall be removed and old renamed to new. In this case, a link named new shall remain visible to other processes throughout the renaming operation and refer either to the file referred to by new or old before the operation began.

The terminology may be a bit confusing because the *old* and *new* files given to `rename` here are the *new version of cpio* and the *old version of cpio*, respectively.

Finally, here is the key to answering your question:

> If the link named by the new argument exists and the file's link count becomes 0 when it is removed and no process has the file open, the space occupied by the file shall be freed and the file shall no longer be accessible. **If one or more processes have the file open when the last link is removed, the link shall be removed before rename() returns, but the removal of the file contents shall be postponed until all references to the file are closed.**

The last sentence means that if any processes have `cpio` open (or are running it) when the `rename` completes, they will continue to see the previous contents of the file until they close the file (or exit).

Arch's `pacman` appears to do roughly the same thing:

```
snprintf(checkfile, len, "%s.paccheck", filename);
...
if(perform_extraction(handle, archive, entry, checkfile, entryname_orig)) {
    errors++;
    goto needbackup_cleanup;
}
...
if(try_rename(handle, checkfile, filename)) {
    errors++;
}
```

Notwithstanding the efforts by the package managers to install new files safely, there can be some problems when a program is updated while in use. The firefox package, for instance, has more than a dozen executables and shared objects. Someone running an old version of firefox during an update may find that an extension they call after the update has completed is incompatible with the old version of firefox. I recently updated firefox on Ubuntu, and apt-get printed out:

> Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.

If you're a system administrator of a multi-user system, it's a good idea to announce pending updates to the user community.